# How do I set ElasticSearch analyzer/tokenizer/filter to get last substring as a token?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I'm having some issues with the ElasticSearch.

Structure: nested keywords delimited with '→'. Example: `→Animal→Mammal→Dog`. There could be any number of nested levels.

What I need is to set `analyzer/tokenizer/filter` to make **ES** search only by deepest keyword. 
For example `→Animal→Mammal→Dog` must be analyzed as Dog, `→Animal` - as Animal, `→Animal→Mammal` - as Mammal.

I tried `PathHierarchy` tokenizer but it's not quite what I need. PathHierarchy tokenizer is splitting →Animal→Mammal→Dog to →Animal, →Animal→Mammal, →Animal→Mammal→Dog.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Pattern Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html), which uses a regular expression to generate tokens.

I used this regex: `^(?:.*→)(.+)$`

Testing it out with the **_analyze** endpoint, like so:

```
POST /_analyze
{
    "tokenizer": {
        "type": "pattern",
        "pattern": "^(?:.*→)(.+)$",
        "group": 1
    },
    "text": "→Animal→Mammal→Dog"
}
```

produced the following result:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "Dog",
            "start_offset": 15,
            "end_offset": 18,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

It is always worth repeating that badly written regular expressions can cause performance problems, so proceed with caution. I believe I wrote a regex that performs well, but I make no guarantees.

If you choose to proceed, you'll need to set up the [Custom Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) in your index settings, and ensure your document mapping contains a field that uses your analyzer.